# The CFX custom tag CFX_imageinfomx was not found in the custom tag database

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, custom-tag

I have added 'CFX_imageinfomx' cfx custom tag in my codes. But it throwing an error 'The CFX custom tag CFX_imageinfomx was not found in the custom tag database'. So I have to register 'imageinfomx.java' into CF admin. So, guys, anybody knows the syntax for 'imageinfomx.java' ? So that, I can generate 'imageinfomx.class' and create custom 'CFX_imageinfomx'.

Thank you.

Comment: *So I have to register 'imageinfomx.java' into CF admin* What have you tried so far? Did you read the [documentation on registering java CFX tags](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Using+the+ColdFusion+Administrator#UsingtheColdFusionAdministrator-CFXTagspage)?  If not, please read it first and give a try. The instructions are pretty clear.  Otherwise, please update your post with the steps you have taken to register the tag in the CF Admin AND any error messages.

Comment: You may ignore this as I could fixed the issue. I was not registered CFX tag file ;-)

Comment: Always good to read the documentation first ;-) Read it. Try some things. Then if you still cannot figure it out, post a question.  BTW, S.O. exists to help other folks too. In cases where you find the solution to your own problem, post it as an "answer". That will help the next guy that runs into the same problem :)